# numpy: cannot import name '_CopyMode'

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting this error when trying to run my imports:

importError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: cannot import name '_CopyMode' from 'numpy._globals'

Here are my inputs, nothing fancy

```
import sys
sys.path.append(home)      # add home folder to module search path
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import tree
from treeviz import tree_print
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
```

I believe my numpy is up to date, and I am using python 3.9 if that helps
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

This happens immediately after the libraries are upgraded.

you can use this :

```
pip uninstall pandas -y
pip uninstall numpy -y
pip install pandas
pip install numpy
```

or use this:

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Comment: Thank you! So this worked, but now I am having the same exact error but with treeviz. I tried doing the same fix as above and apply it to treeviz and sklearn, but I am still getting the same type of error. Where should I go from here?

Comment: @helpmyconda Write your error

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'tree_print' from 'treeviz'

Comment: @helpmyconda .  You must first create a Python file called `treeviz.py` and write the following code inside it.`https://github.com/IndraniMandal/CSC310-S20/blob/master/notes/treeviz.py` .  Then call it by `from treeviz import tree_print` in main.py file.